# How to wrap paragraph around the image?

Tags: html, css, image

I am unable to wrap text around the image. paragraph is not surrounding the image. I have tried float and still it is not working!

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="article">
                <h3>This is the title</h3>
                <hr>
                <img src="imgtest.jpg"></img>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Here is the css code

```
.article{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #FAFAF8;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 4px black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:600px;
}

.article p{
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
}

.article img{
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}

.article h3{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Remove `float:left` from `.article p`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBoEGK

Comment: FYI image elements are self closing. There is no `</img>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `float` of `p`

```css
.article {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #FAFAF8;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 4px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.article p {
  width: 550px;
}
.article img {
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
.article h3 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <h3>This is the title</h3>

  <hr>
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/any"></img>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

removing `float:left;` from `.article p` should solve your problem.